# How to export multiple function or packages in foreach loop in "R"

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I'm trying to decrease run time of my code by using `doParallel` package in R.

I'm calling a function `awareRateSIR` that some extra packages are used in the body of this function. I get some error like

> could not find function "vcount" and..

I know `vcount` is a function of package `igraph` that is used in `awareRateSIR`) but it's not the only one. How can I solve this problem? I've thought I should pass all packages name that is used in my function `awareRateSIR` but I don't know how I cant export multiple function in `foreach` or how I can export multiple package name.

This is my code:

```
tp<-foreach(i=1:iter,  .inorder = FALSE, .export = "awareRateSIR",
          .packages = "igraph", .packages="doParallel")%dopar%{
tp <- awareRateSIR(graphContact, graphCom,state)
return(tp)
}
```

if I don't pass these packages I will get error states some function are unknown if I pass all the packages I will get error:

> Error in foreach(i = 1:iter, .inorder = FALSE, .export =
>   "awareRateSIR",  :  formal argument ".packages" matched by multiple
>   actual arguments"

thanks in advance

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should pass all the packages required, using `c` function, as below :

```
tp<-foreach(i=1:iter,  .inorder = FALSE, .export = "awareRateSIR",
          .packages = c("igraph", "doParallel"))%dopar%{
tp <- awareRateSIR(graphContact, graphCom,state)
return(tp)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you don't need to export any variable, function or package when using foreach.

For variables and functions, they just need to be in the same environment as the `foreach` statement (the better is to make a function where you pass only what you need).

When functions are required from other packages, you just need to use `package::function`, like inside packages.

---

E.g. you can do

```
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cl <- makeCluster(3))

df <- iris

foreach(spec = unique(iris$Species)) %dopar% {
  dplyr::filter(df, Species == !!spec)
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the last point by giving some examples, since I am currently having an exact problem where I tried to use `foreach` on multiple functions each of them contains many other sub-functions?

Comment: @user177196 Please see my edit.